# reactjs - how to get focused virtual element

Tags: reactjs

I have an input list. And want to know how to get current focused inputbox:

```
{list.map((item, index) => {
    return <div>
        <label>{item.name}</label>
        <input {...item} />
    </div>
})}
```

My thought is adding `onFocus` and `onBlur` function in each `inputbox` and saved in state. Is that a better way for this?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Off the top of my head, that's how I would consider doing it.